# Echo data into file from variable then change data to columns

Tags: bash

I'm pretty new to bash but I'm trying to insert some columns into a file. But first I'm trying to echo the data I want into the file but I can't get it working. Here's what I have so far

```
if [ -f $file ]; then
   for i in $data_to_be_echoed; do
      echo  "$data_to_be_echoed > $file"
   done
else
   echo "failed"
fi
```

I've tried the for loop because the variable $data_to_be_echoed should be able to take more than one thing and input it into the file. So for example if I say `$data_to_be_echoed= a b c` then `a b c` should be entered but for the moment I'm just getting a.

Comment: The data to be printed(echoed) should be in `double-quotes` and remove the double quotes around the re-directed file,like: `echo "$data_to_be_echoed" > $file`

Answer (score 1):

You are close. 
To echo the data into a file do:

```
echo  "${data_to_be_echoed}" > ${file}
```

Please notice that this will not append the data. In order to append you need to use `>>`:

```
echo  "${data_to_be_echoed}" >> ${file}
```

If you need a more formatted output I would use printf instead of echo.